# Is there a way to include multiple json files in the response based on the query params?

Tags: json, response, wiremock

I'm trying to use Wiremock standalone process to mock answers from the server. The case is that for the particular endpoint (let's call it /items) I can provide multiple query parameters (like `/items?item=1&item=10&item=12`).
I would like to "build" the response from separate json files based on the query parameters - so build something like jsonBody with array inside containing content of separate json files from `item_1.json`, `item_10` and `item_12`

maybe an example will tell more - here is the mapping file:

```
{
"request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/items",
    "queryParameters": {
        "item": {
            "matches": "1"
        },
        "item": {
            "matches": "10"
        },
        "item": {
            "matches": "12"
        }
    }
},
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
        "items": [
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_{{request.query.item.first}}.json"
        },
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_{{request.query.item.[-1]}}.json"
        },
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_{{request.query.item.last}}.json"
        }]
    },
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

So basically I'm curious if there is a way to respond with multiple files content based on the query parameters in Wiremock?

Unfortunately, for now, I've been just receiving the plain text:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_1.json"
        },
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_10.json"
        },
        {
            "bodyFileName": "items/item_12.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do what you're asking with WireMock out of the box.

Your best bet would be to write a `ResponseDefinitionTransformer` implementation that takes the body JSON format you've described, loads the files referenced and composes them into the response body.

See "Transforming Responses" here: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/

Comment: thanks, will take a deeper look in the Transforming Responses

Answer (score 0):

When using [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Response-Templating), this is possible by setting *UseTransformer* to *true* in this (example) mapping:

```js
{
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "/bodyasfile_transform"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Methods": [
            "get"
        ]
    },
    "Response": {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "Headers": { "Content-Type": "application/xml" },
        "BodyAsFile": "c:\\temp-wiremock\\__admin\\mappings\\_{{request.query.MyUniqueNumber}}_\\MyXmlResponse.xml",
        "UseTransformer": true
    }
}
```

**Update**
With latest version, it's possible to import the contents from a file:

```js
{
    "Guid": "fd8ca21b-db82-48bc-ae5a-fc2153c2b000",
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "/filefragment"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Methods": [
            "get"
        ]
    },
    "Response": {
        "Headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        "BodyAsJson": {
            "file1": "{{File \"c:\\\\temp-wiremock\\\\__admin\\\\mappings\\\\test_1.txt\"}}",
            "file2": "{{File \"c:\\\\temp-wiremock\\\\__admin\\\\mappings\\\\test_{{request.query.MyUniqueNumber}}.txt\"}}"
        },
        "UseTransformer": true
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to construct a response body from e.g. three different files? or I can set only one file's content as BodyAsFile?

Comment: @buccaneer. No, that functionality is not implemented. The `BodyAsFile` can only be generated from 1 file. However, your question sounds like a good idea. I'll investigate if it's possible to add this functionality.